# Sitemaps not updating in ruby on rails sitemap_generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

Using `sitemap_generator` to generate and update sitemaps in my app. It was working fine but from 1 year facing issue that after updating `sitemap.rb` dozens of times and `rake sitemap:refresh` that changes not appear on google search console and it stills show sitemap of old data.

Is there anything I missing which not ping google ?

Comment: Are you saying that there's nothing wrong with your code? The rake task runs without error, and the sitemap updates? Your question is purely in relation to google search console storing an outdated, cached version of your sitemap?

Comment: If the problem has got nothing to do with the code (ruby), then StackOverflow is probably the wrong place for the question.

Comment: Incidentally, there are plenty of tutorials online about removing stale sitemaps from google search console - e.g. [this](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/submit-sitemap-search-engines/#google-submit). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @TomLord yes my code is ok, rake task runs without any error

Comment: I update the cache and add max-age=0 in that also

Comment: So does [this](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/submit-sitemap-search-engines/#google-submit) answer your question?